# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Models'

Tags: python, django

When I'm trying to migrate a new app onto the server i get this error

> AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Models'- in terminal

I'm using PyCharm. I am very fresh to Django and web development so any tips will help. Thanks!

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class product(models.Model):
    item = models.Textfiels()
    description = models.Textfields()
    price = models.Textfields()
```

Comment: did you by any chance wrote `models.Models` (with an `s` at the end) instead of `models.Model` here?

Comment: class product(models.Model):
    item = models.Textfiels()
    description = models.Textfields()
    price = models.Textfields()

Comment: you have a spelling error: `models.Textfiels` but you may need to provide more information about your setup so we can help diagnose the problem. What version of django are you using? Are you using virtualenv? what is your project layout like?

Comment: django 2.0.7 and vitrualenv. Im literally just trying to make my first app. I was using sublime text but preferred pycharm and suddenly it is not working. django.db is unresolved i think that might be the problem

Comment: A quick way to test is to activate your virtualenv and try the import statement in the python interpreter in your terminal: 1) source /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate and 2) run `python` in your terminal and try 3) `from django.db.models import Model`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such class `django.db.models.TextFields` but this works for me on any recent version :

```py
from django.db import models
class product(models.Model):
    item = models.TextFiel()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.TextField()
```

You made 2 typos : the correct name is `TextField` and you typed `Textfields` (Python is case sensitive)

I suspect you didn't setup correctly your project under PyCharm. When correctly setup, it shows warnings on misspelled names (names underlined with red dots with default setting).

Comment: Even when i correct the spellings or typos it has the same problem :/

Comment: If you typed exactly what's in my reply, you're in the right direction. But we need more context to make an real answer to your problem. i.e. did you create a virtualenv with a compatible Python version ? Did you try to create the `product` model in the django console ? What the exact traceback ? ...

Answer (score 0):

There's *another variation* to this question and that is in the form of:

```
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth' has no attribute 'models'
```

As far as I can tell this is typically caused by conflicting imports or improperly imported files. Another cause could be changes to Django's updates but I'm not sure about that as I didn't find any documentation that changed that aspect of the Django library.

Short term solution to this is as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models

class MyClass(models.User): """ """
```

This will allow you to at least test your runserver command and website on a browser of your choosing.

I'm still trying to figure out any other solutions to this problem that can be a fix for individually importing the 'auth' module itself.

At the time of this writing I'm using Django 2.2.6 whereas Django 2.2.7 is out and 2.2.8 is on the way to be released.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution , but when I had this problem it was because in my admin.py file I had

```
from django.contrib import admin

from meetings.models import Meeting, Room

admin.site.register(Meeting, Room)
```

But changing it to solved the issue

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from meetings.models import Meeting, Room

admin.site.register(Meeting)
admin.site.register(Room)
```